# Redux Thunk with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am learning Typescript and I am trying to implement a simple React/Redux app. When I use sync actions it works fine, but the problems are with the async action. I am following the official redux tutorial.

First I declare the state for the session

```
export interface UserSessionState {
  loggedIn: boolean;
}
```

Then I declare the interface for the action

```
interface UpdateSessionAction {
  type: 'USER_LOGIN';
  payload: boolean;
}
```

I export them with Union Types

`export type UserActionTypes = UpdateSessionAction;`

Then I have the actual Action

```
export function updateSession(loggedIn: UserSessionState) {
  return {
    type: 'USER_LOGIN',
    payload: loggedIn,
  };
}
```

I have a fake api call

```
function api() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}
```

And finally the login

```
export const userLogin = (): ThunkAction<
  void,
  {},
  {},
  AnyAction
> => async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
  const res = await api();
  dispatch(updateSession({ loggedIn: res }));
};
```

In the reducer I simply initialize the state

`initialState: UserSessionState = {loggedIn: false}`

Then  I do the normal redux stuff for the reducer.

Finally in my store I call the initial action for checking the state

```
store.dispatch(userLogin());
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

I am missing a `type` but I have no idea what I do wrong.

Comment: In update session you return an action with type USER_LOGIN but this is not a string like it is in the interface - have you declared this elsewhere? If not you'll want to make it a string

Comment: yes it is a normal constant exported `export const USER_LOGIN = 'USER_LOGIN';`, I edited my question just for clarity, thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**In short:**

You get this error because what returned from your `userLogin()` function is a `ThunkAction`, which is missing `type`

**Why this is happening?**

dispatch should accept parameter of type `AnyAction`.
`AnyAction` is a redux type, which extends `Action` (which have a mandatory property  `type`).

This is from the current [redux types file](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts#L20)

```
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}

/**
 * An Action type which accepts any other properties.
 * This is mainly for the use of the `Reducer` type.
 * This is not part of `Action` itself to prevent users who are extending `Action.
 */
export interface AnyAction extends Action {
  // Allows any extra properties to be defined in an action.
  [extraProps: string]: any
}
```

**How to fix it?**
Use `ThunkDispatch` type instead of redux's standard `Dispatch`. The following example and more can be found on [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/milankorsos/ffb9d32755db0304545f92b11f0e4beb)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<MyState, void, Action>) => {
  return {
    onRequestClick: (arg: any) => dispatch(myAsyncAction(arg)),
  };
}
```

Also, see this [article](https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/typescripts-with-redux-redux-thunk-recipe-fcce4ffca405), section **Map Dispatch to Props**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `export function updateSession(loggedIn: UserSessionState) ` but here I want to say that the payload `loggedIn` must be of the shape of UserSessionState and then I have the type for the action that is here 
```interface UpdateSessionAction {
  type: 'USER_LOGIN';
  payload: boolean;
}``` 
Is that correct?

Comment: thanks! now I get `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdateSessionAction` but I will accept your answer anyway because is correct. I need to learn more about typescript, maybe I rushed things moving directly in to async actions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the same thing the question was about, but I stumbled upon the same problem using Redux useDispatch() hook. And again not such a good support for the async action types.
What I eventualy did was to add an AsyncAction type and created a new hook for the typing:

```
// hooks.ts

export type AsyncAction = (dispatch: (action: Action) => any) => void;
export type Dispatcher = (action: AsyncAction | Action) => void
export const useAppDispatch: () => Dispatcher = useDispatch as any;

// async-actions.ts

import {AsyncAction} from "./hooks"

export const myAsyncAction: () => AsyncAction = () => (dispatch: (action: 
Action) => any) => {
// async logic with dispatching goes here:
// dispatch(...)
}

//my-component.tsx

import {myAsyncAction} from "./async-actions"
import {useAppDispatch} from "./hooks"

export const MyComponent = () => { 
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  syncHandler () {
    disaptch ({type: MY_SYNC_ACTION})
  }
  asyncHandler () {
    disaptch (myAsyncAction())
  }
  ...
}
```

Even though a bit Typescrip "hacky" the advantages of this approach are that you get full type check support for the sync and async (Thunk) actions, and from the client (component) point of view there is no difference - no need to use a different type system.