# Getting Next HOC to hook into Redux store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I'm creating a Higher Order Component `withAuth` in order to authenticate some pages in my application. It works by checking the Redux store for a `currentUser`, and if it's not there, will attempt to fetch the current user. The API uses cookie-based sessions, so no request data is required to authenticate the user. Here is the authentication function:

```js
// actions/authActions.ts
const dispatchCurrentUser = () => dispatch => {
  return axios.get('localhost:8000/api/user').then(res => {
    return dispatch({ type: 'GET_CURRENT_USER', payload: res.data })
  }
}
```

Here's what my HOC looks like

```js
// hocs/withAuth.tsx
import cookies from 'js-cookie'
import { NextPageContext } from 'next'
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { dispatchCurrentUser } from '../actions/authActions'
import { RootState } from '../store'
import { IUser } from '../types/auth'
import redirect from '../utils/redirect'

const withAuth = <T extends object>(C: React.ComponentType<T>) => {
    const AuthComponent = (props: any) => {
        return (
            <C {...props} />
        )
    }

    AuthComponent.getInitialProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => {
        const { store, isServer } = context
        const state: RootState = store.getState()
        const currentUser: IUser = state.auth.user

        if (!currentUser) {
            store.dispatch(dispatchCurrentUser()).then(() => null, (error: any) => {
                console.log('User is not authenticated.')
                // Here, user is redirected.
            })
        }

        return { isServer }
    }

    return connect((state: RootState) => state.auth.user, {dispatchCurrentUser})(AuthComponent)
}

export default withAuth
```

The error I'm getting is on `store.dispatch`, which says `"Argument of type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'."` This leads me to believe that the `react-thunk` middleware isn't being picked up, but I'm not sure. Here is what my `makeStore` function looks like:

```js
// store.ts
import { MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { rootReducer } from './reducers'

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

const makeStore: MakeStore = (initialState: any = {}) => {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
}

export default makeStore
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are right, since middleware changes the type of `dispatch` you need to use types provided by `redux-thunk`. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872370/redux-thunk-with-typescript)

Comment: @Shlang Thanks a ton for the link, I'll defintely check this out